# How do I build my maven project that includes my environment variables

Tags: java

please I need help. I'm trying to package my maven build and also include environment variables but my program cannot find the .env file. How can I resolve this issue? I have been using eclipse, but I don't know where I can configure the path to the .env file. I used io.github.cdimascio to read environment variables. The program works fine on my IDE. The trouble starts when I run the program outside the IDE. What should I do?

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.arcalitegames.Main$2.run(Main.java:29)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: io.github.cdimascio.dotenv.DotEnvException: Could not find ./.env on the classpath
        at io.github.cdimascio.dotenv.internal.ClasspathHelper.loadFileFromClasspath(ClassPathHelper.kt:37)
        at io.github.cdimascio.dotenv.internal.DotenvReader.read(DotenvReader.kt:36)
        at io.github.cdimascio.dotenv.internal.DotenvParser.parse(DotenvParser.kt:26)
        at io.github.cdimascio.dotenv.DotenvBuilder.load(Dotenv.kt:119)
        at com.arcalitegames.connector.Devs.getDotenv(Devs.java:10)
        at com.arcalitegames.connector.Connector.<clinit>(Connector.java:14)
        ... 2 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem when I tried to deploy my program to Glassfish. You need to specify a location on the file system like `~` and place your .env file there.

Here is an example on how to do this:

```java
Dotenv env = Dotenv.configure().directory(System.getProperty("user.home")).load();
```

Dotenv should now be able to find the file if you've placed it at ~/.env.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).